# How to avoid Chrome bug with zero height nested flexbox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I've run into a weird situation with flexbox where I'd like to have a nested flex container with a different flex-direction, but for some reason that container takes up 0 height, causing elements to overlap.

https://jsfiddle.net/4co25fau/

Snippet:

```css
body, html, main {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.overflow-y-auto {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<main class="flex flex-column">
  <div class="flex flex-row">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST2</h1>
  </div>
  <h2>SUBTITLE</h2>
  <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-auto">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    
  </div>
</main>
```

This works in Firefox, but not Chrome. Are there any workarounds to avoid it?

Comment: Works on Firefox. Probably just a Chrome bug.

Comment: @Oriol huh, looks like you're right. Bummer, I need this to work in Electron.

Comment: just use flex:1; https://jsfiddle.net/4co25fau/2/ instead of flex-grow since you want it to take what ever room is left. Maybe mind a min-height on the main container  https://jsfiddle.net/4co25fau/3/

Comment: Oooh, looks like the solution isn't `flex:1` (which is identical to `flex-grow:1`) but `flex-basis: 100%` which is the default when using `flex:1`. @GCyrillus if you leave an answer w/ this info I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use the shorthand `flex:1;` to make it simple(and avoid different behavior from  browser to browser)  since the container is suppose to be filling whatever room is left.

https://jsfiddle.net/4co25fau/2/

For safety, i would mind a min-height on the main container to avoid overflow, overlap and  to shrink down to 0 some of the containers.

> **@RahatAhmed wrote:** To clarify, `flex: 1` also sets `flex-basis: 100%` as a default, which is the specific rule that fixes the issue

Comment: To clarify, `flex: 1` also sets `flex-basis: 100%` as a default, which is the specific rule that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Removed `main` from `body, html {}` & added `overflow: hidden` to it, then added `height: 100%` to `.flex` as well.

[see Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4co25fau/4/)

Comment: I'd like for the page to fit the screen and not scroll

Comment: My friend, the overlap is gone and you rate me negative, now you ask something which you have not included in your original question. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4co25fau/4/ but note: the content will never fit if you are setting it in columns down, you will need to scroll eventually somewhere.

Comment: You may have fixed the overlap but you've changed the scenario to do so. Your new solution works, so if you would like to change your answer, i'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I see what you mean now, you are right, the whole document scroll wasn't there previously, I edited it and appreciate if you remove the downvote. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fit the entire screen use

`height:100vh;`

Sorry, I would comment, but I don't have enough rep.